# Search always switches to "relevance" tab

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

In search results "relavance" seldom lists relevant questions/answers first, usually just older q+a, which are usually less relevant for me.

Even worse when I search, then switch to the "active" tab, and then refine the search term (search field inside the page, not the one in the top-right corner) it again switches back to "relevance".

I usually care more about recent activity, to check if some maintenance is necessary. "relevance" usually doesn't help me.

It would be great if my last choice would be reused for subsequent searches, even better, remember it even after page reloads.
At least don't switch back to "relevance" just because I modified the search term.

Comment: This is by design and suggested before,on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102635/could-the-search-result-please-stay-in-the-same-tab-if-i-change-some-search-term

Comment: Here is even a [status-declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135067/search-doesnt-remember-the-tabs)

Comment: Work around: Include something like `created:1y...` if you're sure you don't want to see anything older than a year (or `1m` for a month).